# Which one is best Radeon Software Crimson Edition Beta or Catalyst Software Suite?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, windows-10-v1909

I brought a computer with Radeon HD 7470 graphics card. But My computer graphics card stuck with crimson edition. which one is the best crimson or catalyst.

Comment: Before we all start jumping on this one - this is actually a valid question. When AMD abandoned this generation of GPUs, they left them with 2 choices, the last ever release or a newer beta.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those rare "which is best" questions that actually has a valid, evidence-based answer.

When AMD abandoned this generation of GPUs, they left you with 2 choices, the last ever release 15.7.1 or a newer Crimson beta.

The general guide for this is to use "the release"
Clean install 15.7.1 [there's an option in the Advanced section in the installer to make it do a full clean install]

So long as this then works… stick with it.

The few optimisations added to the beta really only come into play for very few applications & overall it hasn't proven to be more stable than the last 15.7.1 release. As the beta will never be fixed, it's usually not worth the effort.

<sup>I used to work support for a gaming platform & this question cropped up frequently. Answer is based on many empirical trials</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I find that Crimson software is more compatible for Win 10.
While Catalyst last drivers are WHQL approved, the software tends to be more resources demanding for Win 10 and slower to load. Best is to find the last WHQL certified drivers in Crimson software for those old APUs.

https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/amd-radeon-software-crimson-15-12-driver-download.html

Remember to disable your antivirus and firewall before running the installer. Happy gaming.

Comment: Hi! 1st, my apologies if bumping old posts is against etiquette; since the question is directly relevant to me, I'd rather not ask the same question in new thread, but update the older.

I have an ATi Radeon 7500 series (675D, which I believe is an HD7570), and my HDMI display suddenly dropped to VGA 640x and locked the resolution! :(

Reinstalling my ATi Catalyst, I see Crimson (Beta) from ATi site next to Catalyst); a search links this post - so my question to @Bruno is, you link v15.12, but ATi give me 16.2 (Beta) - do you recommend 15.12 as more stable? Or is the v16 beta safe? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, the actual drivers are roughly the same either way; what differs is mostly the "control panel" software bundled with them. "Radeon Crimson" is newer and has more gaming-oriented knobs, e.g. profiles for individual games (and accordingly looks edgier), while "Catalyst Software Suite" is mostly the same app that has existed since Windows XP.

That being said, because AMD doesn't re-bundle new drivers with the old software, the "Crimson" package naturally also has newer drivers as it's the one that continued receiving updates for a while longer after the "Catalyst" package stopped getting updated.

So if you're not going to use the control panel much, then the difference is only whether you want v15.7 or v16.2 of the drivers. There probably won't be much of a difference – most improvements between the two final versions were likely related to their "current" GPUs at that time and no longer had anything to do with the 12-year-old 7470.

You can always have both downloaded and switch between drivers at any time you want, e.g. if a game or some software appears to be unstable with v16.2 there's nothing stopping you from downgrading to v15.7

**Just realized this was posted 3 years ago, have fun with what i answered. If you even see it haha.**